# how to custom spring-security authentication process with my own mechanism

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to secure my app with spring security.

My understanding about spring security is that they check the loaded password from UserDetails against the password user entered.

The thing is my login authentication is inputing username and password into a pl/sql function which will return a result code. So I can't get password from the database.

```
int resultCode = (Integer) jt().execute(
            "{? = call sec$utils.verify_password(?, ?, ?, ?) }",
            new CallableStatementCallback(){
            ...
            stmt.setString(3, username);
            stmt.setString(4, password);
            stmt.execute();
            return stmt.getInt(5);});
```

Is there a way in spring security that I could custom the authentication process so that I could skip the loadUserByUsername and just use my result code as the authentication result?

Please, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do your research Leo, you can answer the question yourself by searching and reading, Spring provides loads of documentation and tutorials to figure out if Spring Security is what you need.

Comment: sorry, I'm still new to this. but I did have been researching about this for almost 4 days. form the ideas I got from spring documents, I'm not sure but I feel the way spring-security validate the authentication request can't satisfy my need. just wondering maybe people here have some tricks that could make spring-security work for my case. or at least, they could give me some suggestions.

Comment: You can write an `AuthenticationProvider` which does this. Provided you don't need any other information about the user, you can just check the result and return a `User` object constructed from the username (with a default role, for example).

Comment: thank you @LukeTaylor, I hadno clue about this before your comment. I did a little research on AuthenticationProvider. I think your idea should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all. Taking password from database from server side application is not vulnerable. Because if you can access the table data then there is no use of it.

Wrong concepts - Spring security is not about returning result code from database.

Its about authentication and authorization. You can enable login and access to various url to specific set of users. It keeps the user information in a static class, so that spring security can identify the role of the user.

Then about spring security. Its still there in the roadmap. But if you need some more advanced framework, you have to look in to `[Apache Shiro][1]`.

If you wanna know how to setup spring security. [link](http://viswanathl.in/2015/01/configuring-spring-security-in-java-web-application/) It is highly customizable.